# C language reading from file to char array

Tags: c, file, char, fgetc

I'm trying to read from file character by character into an array. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   FILE * fp;
   char abc[255];
   int i = 0;

   fp = fopen ("source.c", "r");

   while(fgetc(fp) != EOF)
   {
       fputc(abc[i], FILE *fp );
       printf("%c", abc[i]);
       i++;
   }

   fclose(fp);

   return(0);
}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:19:19: error: expected expression before 'FILE'
     fputc(abc[i], FILE *fp );
```

What does this error mean? What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: int fputc ( int character, FILE * stream ); (in your case  fputc(abc[i], fp );)

Comment: In `c`, you don't pass arguments types as function parameters, get rid of `FILE *` in your `fputc` call. But that whole line is a problem anyway. `fputc` attempts to _write_ a character to the stream.. you've opened this file for reading only with the `"r"` mode. As the answers suggest, just dump the `fputc` line entirely. If you're trying to write something to a file too, you'll have to open one for writing.

Comment: this line: `while(fgetc(fp) != EOF)` is reading the character from the file, storing it nowhere.  Suggest: `char abc[255]; int ch; for( i = 0; i < 255 && (ch = fgetc(fp) != EOF)); i++ ) {  abc[i] = (char)ch;  }`

Comment: when calling the function: `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 2):

The error is about the incorrect usage of `fputc()`. The second argument is a *stream*.
But in your case, you don't need a call to `fputc()` since your are using printf() as well.

You have another problem. You don't store the char read from the file at all. Do something like:

```
   int in;

   while((in=fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
   {
       in = abc[i];
       printf("%c", abc[i]);
       i++;
   }
```

Some general comments:

- Always do error checking for all standard functions. What if `fopen()` fails?
- Your array can only hold upto 256 chars. What if the file `source.c` has more chars?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE * fp;
  char abc[255];
  int i = 0;

  fp = fopen ("source.c", "r");

  // we need to make sure that we can fit
  // into buffer - that's why we check whether i < 255
  while(i<255 && (abc[i] = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
  {
    printf("%c", abc[i]);
    i++;
  }
  // if we are way before end of the buffer
  // we should think about terminating string
  if(i<254)
    abc[i] = '\0';
  else
    // otherwise, we have to make sure that last character
    // in buffer is zero
    abc[254] = '\0';
  printf("%s", abc);

  fclose(fp);

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: It works now. But what is this part for?
if(i<254)
    abc[i] = '\0';
  else
    abc[254] = '\0';
  printf("%s", abc);

Comment: In C, you have to make sure that string (array of characters) is terminated with '\0' (end of string). In this case we have two situations. Buffer fits into array and we make sure to put '\0' at last position. Otherwise, we overwrite the last character and we put '\0' at the very end.